# Create groups based on the participant choices

Tags: excel

I have a long list of participants who have chosen two other colleagues to be within their group. I would like to give them one of the two.

Sheet 1:
Column A - name of participant
Column B - name of Choice 1
Column C - name of choice 2.

On Sheet 2 I would like a long group list that I could separate into the number of groups and then manually tweak.

In my mind is a formula using VLOOKUP and it should work but I have no idea how. I think that I have to enter the name of `Participant 1` in Sheet2 A1. The formula in A2 will then look up A1 on sheet 1 and return either B1 (`Choice 1`) or C1 (`choice 2`) if `Choice 1` is already in the list.

Comment: You should try something and come back with a more specific question.  You should try the Vlookup as you mentioned and also look into a pivot table.  If you encounter problems with those, then ask us about those specific problems.

Comment: [Vlookup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBEyr-9ZSN4 )